# In Angular.js,IS there any way of restricting service's visibility to one module or to a 'class' of modules.?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

In **Angular.js**, all the services defined on a module are 
visible to all the other modules.*Is there any way of restricting service's visibility 
to one module or a subset of modules*..? 
    .I want some of my services to use generic names for their purposes, and not to be bothered by others.

Answer (score 0):

Module can be injected to another module. Depending on your accesibility and visibility if you create sub modules, then combine those module to create your required module. This way you can solve the problem.

Suppose you have 4 service SEV1, SEV2, SEV3 and SEV4.
 But you want SEV1 as Global but SEV2 and SEV3 are Specific to a perticular module MODULE1. and SEV4 to MODULE2.

So you create followings
COMONMODULE(SEV1), SUBMODULE1(SEV2,SEV3) and SUBMOUDLE2(SEV4)

Now use COMONMODULE as injection to all of your module and SUBMODULE1 where ever required. In this way hopefully you can solve your problem.